# How can I view or inspect the $PATH for a bundle exec?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am troubleshooting a certain gem (spree_cmd) and want to know where "bundle exec" expects the binaries to be.

```
...bundler/shared_helpers.rb:151:in `bin_path': can't find executable spree.
```

When I `echo $PATH`, there is a "spree" somewhere. Confirmed with `which spree`.

Comment: Is spree defined in your Gemfile or a dependency of any of the gem sin your Gemfile?

Comment: It is defined in my gemfile, yes. gem 'spree', :path => '../gems/spree' (could be a git repo too, though) Spree then depends on spree_cmd, which has the binaries. Problem is a bug in edge spree, where bin is not passed along properly. Which I am trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a clearer understanding of your issue, I can't offer anything specific.

You can figure out where it is storing your binaries by doing `bundle exec which some_binary_from_gemfile` it will tell you where that binary is located.

According to the [docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html#ENVIRONMENT-MODIFICATIONS) it also looks like you can add your own bin directory by setting the `$BUNDLE_BIN_PATH` environment variable.

Another thing you could do would be to `bundle install --binstubs` which would create a folder  in the root directory containing all of your binaries.

If your binary isn't being added to the path, the first place I would look is your .gemspec, (you must [specify where the bin directory is](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#bindir) with `spec.bindir = 'bin'`). I see in the current spree_cmd gem (0.0.4) that it looks correct (haven't tried running it). If that looks correct, then make sure your binary is in the dir you specified, make sure it is executable, make sure the shebang is correct, make sure it's named the same as the binary you're trying to invoke.

Comment: The specification in the gemspec was indeed wrong. Thanks for giving me the information I needed for the troubleshooting!